# How to make slime with procedural bubbles using Geometry Nodes?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, geometry-nodes, instances

I've just installed Blender 3.0 and it has renewed my curiosity for Geometry Nodes. I was thinking of what might be a fun use for Geom Nodes and the idea oozed into my head: SLIME! Because slime has these little air bubbles that move with the slime as it stretches and oozes...

Reference:

[image: Slime with bubbles]

Rules for the bubbles:

1. They need to stay *inside* of the mesh volume.
2. Their positions should move with mesh deformations.
3. Bubble normals should be inside-out (as you do with bubbles inside a liquid).

Note: There probably isn't a way to make bubbles flow during a fluid sim, as the fluid mesh topology changes *completely* in each frame. I think that can't be helped. But if someone really clever thinks of a way, please share!

I'm looking forward to what the Geom Node wizards here can teach me... thanks!

**Edit:** As I'm digging through the types of Geometry Nodes here in the manual, I'm not seeing a lot in the way of volume-based nodes. But maybe the [Raycast Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/raycast.html) can be used to check if a point is inside a volume or not(?). This could be trickier than I first thought.

Comment: just in "theory" i am convinced you can do fluid sim with GN because you can control every vertex with it (via SetPosition Node). The question is: does it make sense in terms of performance and expense. So i personally would always try to go the way with flipfluids or any other way which already have fluid sims inside ;)

Comment: @Chris Interesting. It's been a while since I've done fluid sims in Blender, so I have some catching up to do. I didn't realize FLIP Fluids does high-viscosity slime type fluids as well. I'm not sure that it does bubbles inside the volume though. Are you able to provide more info on this? I guess I should open up this question to include methods beyond just GN...

Comment: yes, flip fluids has a viscosity value as well as mantaflow has. And it is still remarkable quicker than mantaflow is. So i never regret buying that ;)